# Multiplication of two positive numbers gives a negative output in Python 3

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a DataFrame `df1` :

```
df1.head() = 

             wght          num_links 
id_y  id_x                      
 3     133   0.000203          2      
       186   0.000203          2 
 5     6     0.000203          2      
       98    0.000203          2      
       184   0.000203          2
```

I need to calculate a variable called `thr`,

```
thr = N*(N-1)*2,
```

where `N`is the number of rows of `df1`.

The problem is that when I calculate `thr`,Python throws a negative value(although all of the inputs are positive):

```
ipdb> df1['wght'].count()*(df1['wght'].count()-1)*2
-712569744
```

**Possible hint**

The number of rows N is

```
ipdb> df1['wght'].count() 
137736
```

therefore,

```
ipdb> 137736*137735*2
37942135920.
```

Taking into account that the max value that can be assigned to a `int32` is `2147483647`, I suspect that NumPy considers `type(thr) = <int32>`, when it should be `<int64>`. Does this make sense?

Please note that I have not written the code that generates `df1` because

```
ipdb> df1['wght'].count() 
137736
```

However, if it is needed to reproduce the error, let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you on a 32 bit system? Unless there is a bug in pandas, all count values are typically of C's `ssize_t` or equivalent, which will be a 32 bit integer on 32 bit systems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are experiencing `np.int32` overflow, so just use `len(df)` instead of `df.column.count()`.

Here is a small demo:

```
In [149]: x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(137736, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))

In [150]: x.A.count() * (x.A.count() - 1) * 2
Out[150]: -712569744

In [151]: len(x) * (len(x) - 1) * 2
Out[151]: 37942135920

In [153]: type(x.A.count())
Out[153]: numpy.int32

In [154]: type(len(x))
Out[154]: int
```

Answer (score 2):

If you get the type of `count()` (i.e. `type(df1['wght'].count())`) you'll receive:

```
<class 'numpy.int32'>
```

So try your computation with:

```
n = df1['wght'].count().astype(np.int64)
n*(n-1)*2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `df1['wght'].count()` to long constructor like this, to ensure it is long.

```
N = long(df1['wght'].count())
```

Although storing to any variable

```
N = df1['wght'].count()
```

should work as the class int has a `__mul__` method (which implements *) that creates a long result when required.

Also Python 3.x has "unified" int and long which also takes care of the bug.