# Pandas rolling on positive value gets negative result

Tags: python, pandas

I am using `rolling` function to get sum of a column where all values are positive.

My code is `df[col].rolling(4).sum()` and the original data frame is:

[image: df]

After rolling became:

[image: df_roll]

From roll 13920 onwards all values turn to negative. Don't understand why.

If anyone knows what happened?

Comment: Perhaps this could be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37880740/multiplication-of-two-positive-numbers-gives-a-negative-output-in-python-3

Comment: Thanks! This does help, there is numeric overflow.